# Low score in Linear Regression with discrete attributes

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to do a linear regression in my dataframe. The dataframe is about apple applications, and I want to predict the notes of applications. The notes are in following format:

```
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
...
5.0
```

My code is:

```
atributos = ['size_bytes','price','rating_count_tot','cont_rating','sup_devices_num','num_screenshots','num_lang','vpp_lic']
atrib_prev = ['nota']

X = np.array(data_regress.drop(['nota'],1))
y = np.array(data_regress['nota'])

X = preprocessing.scale(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

print(accuracy)
```

But my accuracy is 0.046295306696438665. I think this occurs because the linear model is predicting real values, while my 'note' is real, but at intervals. I don't know how to round this values before the `clf.score`.

Answer (score 1):

First, for regression models, `clf.score()` calculates [R-squared value](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html), not accuracy. So you would need to decide if you want to treat this problem as a classification problem (For some fixed number of target labels) or a regression problem (for a real-valued target)

Secondly, if you insist on using regression models and not classification, you can call `clf.predict()` to first get the predicted values and then round off as you want to, and then call `r2_score()` on actual and predicted labels. Something like:

```
# Get actual predictions
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# You will need to implement the round function yourself
y_pred_rounded = round(y_pred)

# Call the appropriate scorer
score = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_rounded)
```

You can look at the [sklearn documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules) for available metrics in sklearn.